# Input string was not in a correct format (Decimal to String)

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, decimal

am trying to convert a decimal to a string which I have done sucesfully in the past but for some reason its deciding not to work now. I really can't get my head around it, I have set it to decimal in SQL Management Studio and used linq to entites to pass it through but for some bizarre reason unknown to mankind it thinks am asking for a datetime.

Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tblTest t = new tblTest();

                t.tDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxDecimal.ToString());

                t.Add(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: What is the value of `tbxDecimal.ToString()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should always use [System.Decimal.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) instead of Convert.ToDecimal()

Second, assuming you're using some form of hungrian notation, and tbx means "textbox" in your notation, you're trying to convert a textbox, not the text IN the textbox.

instead of

```
tbxDecimal.ToString()
```

you need

```
tbxDecimal.Text.ToString()
```

Finally, have you put a breakpoint in to find out what the value you're trying to convert really is?  It may be different than you're expecting.

Comment: Lmao yeah I was pretty dumb not to see that one... Thanks

Comment: I was getting this error because my decimal number was displaying with a space between the negative sign and the number, like - 3.14 instead of -3.14.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is because the string uses a dot instead of a coma, or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `tbxDecimal.ToString()== string.Empty` ?  Decimal.Parse will throw an exception if the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Fredrik's answer: is there a CultureInfo/Localization mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it's datetime? Could you post the actual string?

Pay attention to decimal separator - '.' vs. ','